# Approach to check if callback was last fired?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a function which looks like that:

```
function update() {
    buildUpdate(function(result) {
        // send result to clients
    });
}
```

This normally works correctly. However if I do something like:

```
// data state 1

update(); // this time, buildUpdate() won't take a long time

// do some work resulting in:
// data state 2

update(); // this time, buildUpdate() will take a long time
          // and thus will finish after the third call

// do some work resulting in:
// data state 3

update(); // this time, buildUpdate() won't take a long time
```

As expected, the clients will receive three updates. However they are in the wrong order because the third call of `update()` did finish earlier than the second. From the clients point of view it looks like this:

- Receives update calculated based on data state 1
- Receives update calculated based on data state 3
- Receives update calculated based on data state 2 (this update should not be sent)

Is there any design pattern or function which helps to avoid such a case?

Note: It doesn't matter if a client doesn't receive all updates. What matters is only that the last one received must be consistent with the current data state.

My idea was to generate on each invocation of `update()` a random ID. Afterwards I check in the callback whether its ID matches the last one that was generated. However the generation of the ID itself introduces a new async calculation and leads to much more code on each usage.

Comment: A: Regardless of your platform being node.js this question has nothing to do with node.js B: What do you want to have happen when update is called a second time?  Given an answer to B I think I can help you out with a better idea than your random ID

Comment: @GeorgeJempty A: You're right, I apologize for the wrong tagging. B: See the revised question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to add a callback

```
function update(callback) {
    buildUpdate(function(result) {
        // send result to clients

        if (typeof callback == 'function') callback();
    });
}
```

and do

```
 update(function() {           // when the first one finishes
     update(function() {       // run the second one
         update(function() {   // and when the second is finished, the third
              update();        // and so on....
         });
     });
 });
```

If you add the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) middleware you would have more advanced methods available to deal with async behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way that can be applied to more than two update calls? (like in the revised example)

Comment: @ted - Apply it as many times as you'd like (see updated answer) , but if you're going to this many, many times, there are better ways, for instances recursion comes to mind, but it's a little more complicated than just nesting the functions.

Comment: You should consider using a jquery promise object http://api.jquery.com/promise/ to handle your asynchronous issues.

Answer (score 0):

My current approach works but is probably not the best solution.
**Please submit an answer if you know a better way.**

```
var outdated = function(f, cb) {
    var counter = 0;
    var finished = -1;
    return function() {
        var no = counter++;
        a = [].slice.call(arguments);
        a.unshift(function() {
            if(no > finished) {
                finished = no;
                cb.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
        f.apply(this, a);
    };
};
```

Let's consider the following example:

```
var example = outdated(function(cb, a) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(a);
    }, a * 1000);
}, function(c) {
    console.log('finished '+c);
});

example(1);
example(4);
example(2);
```

This will yield to the following output:

```
finished 1
finished 2
```

`finished 4` is not being printed as it was called before `finished 2` but ended after it.

To solve the actual problem as stated in the question, I would call the function like this:

```
var update = outdated(buildUpdate, function(result) {
    // send update to clients
});

update();
// do some changes
update();
```